# PHP Get username from Database, display username on page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently trying to get the username from my database into my webpage and display it. I am not having much luck, this is the code that I have so far. Should work, but the $username variable is undefined, not sure why.

```
        <?php
    /* Database Information */
    $server = '127.0.0.1';
    $database = 'nicedevelopment';
    $dbuser = 'root';

    /* Database Connection */
    $connect = mysql_connect("$server", "$dbuser")
        OR die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("$database", $connect);

    /* Escape String */
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($connect);

    /* Find and get row*/
    $getit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'",$connect);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($getit);

    $username = $row['username']
        ?>

  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo center"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></a>
```

**This is my login page!**

```
    <?php
 require('connect.php');
    session_start();
    // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
        if (isset($_POST['email'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
        $email = stripslashes($email);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
        //Checking is user existing in the database or not
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email='$email' and password='".md5($password)."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        header("Location: dashboard.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
    }else{
    echo "<div class='form'><h4>Email/password is incorrect.</h4><br/>Click here to <a href='index.php'>Login</a></div>";
  }
    }else{
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and removed!!

Comment: why use `mysql` ? , hmm, your problem is here `$connect = mysql_connect("$server", "$dbuser");` you forget to send password to function, try like this `$connect = mysql_connect("$server", "$dbuser","")` if you don't set password for you root user

Comment: Actually lot of other errors are there. I think you want to show username after login. If is it so, things need to change. `$username = mysql_real_escape_string($connect);` totally wrong

Comment: In other words, your database query is saying `Get everything from users where the username is mysql_connect("$server", "$dbuser")` - this doesn't make any sense... You first want to log the user in, create a session and use the session to show their username - a query isn't needed.

Comment: Your code makes little sense. You search for the row in the table `WHERE username = '$username'`. If you already have `$username`, why do you need to search for it to print the username?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Since the user is only able to login with their email, you won't be able to use a `session` to display their username *(unless you want to display their email!)*. Your best bet would be to use a query which selects the username from a table where the email equals the email they used to login with:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'"
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$username = $row['username'];

echo $username;
?>
```

**Original Answer**

According to your query, you're trying to select a username from the database which is equal to `$connect = mysql_connect("$server", "$dbuser")` - this doesn't make sense at-all.

You first want to log the user in, like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
}

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

To then display the name of the user, simply use these two lines of code:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['username];
```

Note: this is a very basic script. It doesn't prevent any forms of SQL Injection Attacks and doesn't validate the username and password - it's just an example to get you on the right track.

Comment: I already have a login page, i edited the post so you can see the code i am using there. When the user logs in he get redirected to dashboard.php which is where i want his username to display.

Comment: Your login form doesn't allow the user to login with a username. Do you store the users `email` and username` in the same row in a database? If so, your best option would be `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email`, then get the `username`. I will update my post with this.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Try this code, fill the password field and let me know about the output. Although it is not clear where is your $username variable coming from.

Edit: I have seen that you updated your question, so I modified the code based on that. **I also edited the code based on the feedback of the questioner.**

```
<?php
$dbservername = "127.0.0.1";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "password";
$dbname = "nicedevelopment";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$post_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$post_email'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo "username: " . $row['username'] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I think you meant `$email = "$_POST['email']";`

Comment: No problem! Also, you don't need to use a `while` loop... should be `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()`

Comment: I used that part from my own code, but I modified that too. Now the only question is that it is working for him or not.

Comment: Got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dashboard.php on line 23

Comment: I have updated the code. So I hope it will work this time, but make sure to call this php script only after a successful login attempt.